# How can I randomly change the values of some rows in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe like below:

```
UserId    ProductId    Quantity
1         1            6
1         4            1
1         7            3
2         4            2
3         2            7
3         1            2
```

Now, I want to randomly select the 20% of rows of this DataFrame, using df.sample(n), and change the value of the Quantity column of these rows to zero. I would also like to keep the indexes of the altered rows. So the resulting DataFrame would be:

```
UserId    ProductId    Quantity
1         1            6
1         4            1
1         7            3
2         4            0
3         2            7
3         1            0
```

and I would like to keep in a list that the rows 3 and 5 have been altered. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By using [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
dfupdate=df.sample(2)
dfupdate.Quantity=0
df.update(dfupdate)
update_list = dfupdate.index.tolist() # from  cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  :)
df
Out[44]: 
   UserId  ProductId  Quantity
0     1.0        1.0       6.0
1     1.0        4.0       0.0
2     1.0        7.0       3.0
3     2.0        4.0       0.0
4     3.0        2.0       7.0
5     3.0        1.0       2.0
```

Comment: Awesome. +1 Add that `update_list = dfupdate.index.tolist()` and it is done.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ modified it ~ :)

Comment: This is great and do we need sample (2), to change the column Quantity. Why not use a random 2 digits between 0 and df len  using `loc`. Just saying

Comment: @Bharathshetty it is just base on OP's effort

Comment: Great! Could I also update my DataFrame using `df.loc[update_list, 'Quantity'] = 0`?

Comment: @DimitrisPoulopoulos Yes, that is also a valid solution, but was deleted because it was similar to this (I guess).

Comment: As a reference if anyone stumbles on this with a similar problem: pandas _update_ function does **not** work for replacing values with NaN: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

Answer (score 15):

Using `loc` to change the data i.e

```
change = df.sample(2).index
df.loc[change,'Quantity'] = 0
```

Output:

```
  UserId  ProductId  Quantity
0       1          1         0
1       1          4         1
2       1          7         3
3       2          4         0
4       3          2         7
5       3          1         2
```

```
change.tolist() : [3, 0]
```